# Coldfusion Date conversion convert yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss to date and time

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I have a date coming in like this:

`2020-02-09:08:57:51`

How do i convert this to its proper date and time.

I have tried `#PARSEDATETIME(myd,"yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss")#`

but it returns `{ts '2024-09-09 08:00:51'}`  which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [`dateTimeFormat`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateTimeFormat.html), you have to use a different character for minutes: `n`

```
ts = "2020-02-09:08:57:51";
dt = parseDateTime(ts, "yyyy-mm-dd:HH:nn:ss");

writeOutput(dt);
// {ts '2020-02-09 08:57:51'}
```

`dt` is a date object, its `toString` implementation returns an ODBC timestamp literal in ColdFusion.

For future reference, this is what the docs say:

```
d: Day of the month as digits; no leading zero for single-digit days.
dd: Day of the month as digits; leading zero for single-digit days.
EEE: Day of the week as a three-letter abbreviation.
EEEE: Day of the week as its full name.
m: Month as digits; no leading zero for single-digit months.
mm: Month as digits; leading zero for single-digit months.
mmm: Month as a three-letter abbreviation.
mmmm: Month as its full name.
M: Month in year.
D: Day in year.    yy: Year as last two digits; leading zero for years less than 10.
yyyy: Year represented by four digits.
YYYY: Week year represented by four digits.
Y: Week year.
YY: Week year as last two digits; leading zero for years less than 10.
G: Period/era string. (e.g. BC, AD)
h: hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock)
hh: hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock)
H: hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock)
HH: hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock)
n: minutes; no leading zero for single-digit minutes
nn: minutes; a leading zero for single-digit minutes
s: seconds; no leading zero for single-digit seconds
ss: seconds; leading zero for single-digit seconds
l or L: milliseconds, with no leading zeros
t: one-character time marker string, such as A or P
tt: multiple-character time marker string, such as AM or PM
w: Week of the year as digit.
ww: Week of the year as digits. Leading zero for single-digit week.
W: Week of the month as digit.
WW: Week of the month as digits. Leading zero for single-digit week.
```

Comment: @JeffShain - Since you didn't mention your cf version, keep in mind date mask characters may vary by version. The list above should be good for modern versions like CF2016+. Earlier versions may differ slightly.

Comment: I think these mask characters go back to at least version 7.

Comment: The characters maybe(?) but how they're interpretated has definitely changed. I don't think parseDateTime even accepted a mask in 7. Try the code above in Cf10 and 2016 to see the differences.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind: Date masking can be different based on the different languages used through your application. Be sure to check which context you are in when you are converting it. `YYYY` and `yyyy` will drive you absolutely nuts, because they are the same for all but about 3 or 4 days of a year. And those days happen when most people are on New Years vacation. Also, the different date formatting functions may use different masks. It's been a while since I've mentioned it, but _I HATE DATES_.